# Quantum Programming . . . How?

Tags: quantum-computing, q#, qiskit

So I understand some of the basic ideas with setting up a quantum program . . .  libraries, classical logic feeding to a quantum API, all that. I even get that there are quantum operations you apply.

Where I am struggling is how do you figure out the correct quantum operations to apply for a given problem?

Can someone walk through a basic problem and how to derive the quantum equation to solve it?

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at the algorithms section of the [Qiskit textbook](https://community.qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/teleportation.html)

Comment: I definitely will! Sounds like a good place to start at least 

Comment: Another good place to start is the [Quantum Kata tutorials](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas#tutorial-topics).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Qiskit Textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/preface.html).
Be careful, you can apprehend the way quantum computing works, there is another step understanding how to apply it. I compare it to coding in assembler. You can understand quite easily how it works but it needs some work to make a real case from it.